# Powershell 5.1 snap in registration errors

Tags: powershell, pssnapin

To preface this, this script i made that involves creating 2007 MS Exchange mailboxes had worked a week or two ago, and suddenly gave me an error (below) from this:

`Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin`

error given:

`Add-PSSnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 5.`

I have been all over and can't find anything to help. the command `get-PsSnapins -registered` doesn't give me anything. I did a clean windows 7 install, did all the windows updates, everything i can think of. I've tried running it without that snap-in but powershell doesn't recognize it as a cmdlet. All out of ideas and options

I am an admin on the network, machine, and running powershell as an admin. Execution policy is set to unrestricted

Comment: Check `Get-PSSnapIn -Registered`.  Did you recently upgrade to 5.1?

Comment: As i said in the post, get-pssnapin -registered returns nothing. I've had 5.1 for a while

Comment: Did you get this solved @toupin

Answer (score 1):

As an FYI, PowerShell 5.0+ is incompatible with Microsoft Exchange 2013: [Product Compatibility Status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/5.1/productincompat#incompatible)

You should use PSRemoting to connect to the Exchange server, and run from there [Directly Loading Exchange 2010 or 2013 SnapIn Is Not Supported](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rmilne/2015/01/28/directly-loading-exchange-2010-or-2013-snapin-is-not-supported/):

```
$ExSession =  New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri 'http://exServer01.contoso.com/PowerShell/' -Authentication Kerberos
Import-PSSession ($ExSession) -AllowClobber
```

If this was working for you in the past, make sure that you are launching the 32 bit **Windows PowerShell (x86)** version of PowerShell, as the Exchange Snapin is not 64 bit.

Comment: Sorry, im on exchange 2007

Comment: also i never had a powershell update (that i knew of) and it was working without a remote session a week or two ago

Comment: @toupin win7 only comes with V2.  Search for KB3191566

Comment: Have you tried launching the 32 bit Windows PowerShell (x86) version of PowerShell, as the Exchange Snapin is not 64 bit. (see edits)

Comment: i tried launching in x86 and the same error came up. 

@TheIncorrigible1 i have that downloaded already

sorry guys, back at work

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Get-Module -Name Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin -ListAvailable | Import-Module
```